# Pandas is not installed in virtualenv although it seems so

Tags: python, pandas, virtualenv

I want to use pandas in a script running in a virtualenv of python 3 in a EC2 machine. I installed pandas as soon as I created the virtualenv but the script throws me the classic error that pandas does not exists.

Anyway, for reinstalling again I do the following commands:

```
cd ga_venv #name of my virtualenv
source bin/activate
pip install pandas
```

Then, I get that pandas is successfully installed. Right after the installation, I make `pip freeze` and pandas does not show up. Then, I try to uninstall it and it appears `WARNING: Skipping pandas as it is not installed.`

I have tried also with `pip3 install pandas`. I attach a screenshot where you can see that the virtualenv is correctly activated and it says pandas is installed, but at the same time it cannot be uninstalled because it is not installed:
[image]

How could I solve this in order to use pandas inside my venv?

Comment: You need to install it using the pip in your venv, e.g. in anaconda something like `../anaconda/envs/cc-dev/bin/pip install pandas`

Comment: If I am not using the pip of the venv, shouldn't I be able to uninstall it anyway because I would be using the same incorrect pip for the two commands?

Comment: after installing, have you checked to see if it's in the site packages floder in your ga_venv folder?

Comment: Yes, and it's not there. As shown in the picture, it seems to be installed in dist-packages instead of site packages folder, although it is not really there neither. I have tried what you said as `/home/ec2-user/ga_venv/bin/pip install pandas`and the results are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it was being installed in the folder dist-packages (I don't know why, because other packages have been installed with success in site-packages) so I just made:

```
pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default pandas
```